# v-on:click and event triggering on inner elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of tabs set up with the following markup:

```
<li v-on:click.stop="changeTab()" id="bookings">
    <i class="fa fa-scissors" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Bookings</span>
</li>
```

The changeTab() method is:

```
changeTab: function() {
    window.location.hash = this.activeTab = event.srcElement.id;
}
```

The issue here is that if I click on the inner elements, i / span, then it sets the incorrect ID (none) and its the srcElement. Is there a way to now allow this to happen? Can I make the wrapper the only click that is listened to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `event.currentTarget.id` instead of event.srcElement.id